# What are the names of surgical instruments?

Tags: anatomy, surgery

> **My questions**
>
> - Please tell me the names of scissors  (1) and (2) of the following
>     figure.
> - Please also refer to the differences in characteristics of (1) and
>     (2) for the case when we use them for the autopsy of mice or rats. 
>     What role do these play in mouse/rat anatomy?

[image]
It seems to be used for the autopsy of mice or rats.

Scissors (2) is probably an ophthalmic scissor. Am I right?

Scissors (1) has longer blades than (2). Both (1) and (2) seem to be "double sharp" type (see the edges of blades.)

The coin (3) is to display the scale. This is a 10-yen coin (Japanese coin); the diameter of this is 23.5mm.

P.S. I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Comment: ＠John Thank you for your comment. If I don't get an answer for a while, I will move the question to the location you taught me.

Comment: Are you sure there are different names for them?

Comment: @Carey Gregory Thank you for your comment. I do not know. But are surgical scissors and ophthalmic scissors, or both ophthalmic scissors?

Comment: To my untrained eye they look very similar. Why do you believe one of them to be ophthalmic scissors?

Comment: @ Carey Gregory In the past, I used them to dissect mice in class.
I've heard that ophthalmic scissors are optimal for dissecting mice.
There is no further basis. Certainly, ① and ② are only slightly different in blade length.

Comment: They are dissecting scissors. I wish I could say more. The size difference makes no difference. If they had curved blades, or if one of the blades was blunt, it would be different, but alas... Scissors used in opthalmic surgery are much daintier.

Comment: @ Carey Gregory Thank you. Roger. Could you submit your answer formally? I want to accept your answer.

Comment: Your last comment here did not ping (i.e. didn't send notification) to Carey, so they probably never noticed the comment. If you put a space after the `@` character, it won't ping, you should have the name right after that character, like you did once, but then for some reason started adding a space. Dunno if still relevant, but you can still ping Carey to draw their attention.

Comment: @Carey Gregory   Could you submit your answer formally? I want to accept your answer.

Comment: I didn't offer an answer. I think you meant to address your comment to @anongoodnurse. And Shadow is right that I never got pinged.